# Convert categorical data to be numeric data scikit-learn optimization

Tags: python, scikit-learn

I have a dataset with categorical data and i convert the data to be numeric with DictVectorizer.

```
# training data
vect = DictVectorizer(sparse=False)
x =  vect.fit_transform(samples)
# test data
vect.transform(samples)
```

but this code make memory problems in large datasets because it's cost too much memory when every category consist of many types .

I want a Solution or algorithms to solve problem of memory cost

Comment: try changing sparse to `true`

Comment: Thanks Harpal. I used vectorizer to prepare data to DecisionTree Classifier.    When I change sparse to true . I got that error TypeError: A sparse matrix was passed, but dense data is required. Use X.toarray() to convert to a dense numpy array.

Comment: I know I can use X.todense() but it will increase memory footprint and that what makes memory error.

Comment: Is there's a better technique to vectorize large data ?

Comment: Update your version of scikit-learn. We supported sparse data in trees for a while now.

Comment: Thanks Andreas . It's works now! . last question ,  Which algorithms work with sparse arrays ?.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. upgrade scikit-learn
2. change sparse to true

   vect = DictVectorizer(sparse=False)